# MySQL Hash password stored with colon separator

Tags: mysql, hash, dump

I have a MySQL dump and passwords are stored a format like this, with a colon separating parts of the hash:

```
40f4321af47d6293aaa4b16d9feb74b3:k0u3RjWCU29Qam4IKNmE8EkhrxXK
```

Which hash kind is it?

Comment: Two dots is called _colon_.

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be a Joomla hash:salt.   the actual has will be some form of MD5

Comment: Effectively it's a joomla framework, how to decrypt this hash ? ;)

Comment: @jotifit The point of a one-way hash (especially when salted) is to make decryption impossible.

Comment: @jotifit You don't decrypt hashes. When someone enters a password, you hash it, and check whether it matches the saved hash.

Comment: Ok because i have seen python cracker ? does not work ?

Comment: If you are trying to decrypt someones password, well, thats why its hashed with a salt.So that YOU wont decrypt it any soon, or easy.